# Sorting of list which contains dictionary in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have 2 quite nested Python dictionaries and I would like to compare them (My real Json files contains hundred thousands lines). These dictionaries contain lists and these lists contain dictionaries. The order of elements are not fixed and it is not problem in case of dictionary but it is in case of a list. So I have to sort the elements in my structure.

I have written an sorting algorithm which sorts the items recursively in my data structure.

My code works as expected with Python2.7 executable but it doesn't work with Python3.6.6 executable.

I have already read the official Python documentation and I know that the `list.sort()` has been changed between Python2 and Python3, but I feel it is a quite big limitation in Python3.

I am familiar with the `key` parameter but it doesn't solve my problem. Furthermore, the keys are not the same in the dicts.

So, my question: Is it possible to sort a list which contains more type elements like in my case?

**Code:**

```
test_1 = {"aaa": 111, "bbb": 222, "ccc": [{"o": [1, "t"]}, "a", "b", 1, [1, 2, [4, 3, [6, 5]]]]}
test_2 = {"bbb": 222, "aaa": 111, "ccc": [[2, 1, [3, 4, [5, 6]]], 1, "a", "b", {"o": ["t", 1]}]}


def list_sort(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        l.sort()
        for x in l:
            list_sort(x)


def dict_sorter(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dict_sorter(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            v.sort()
            for x in v:
                if isinstance(x, dict):
                    dict_sorter(x)
                elif isinstance(x, list):
                    list_sort(x)


print("\n\nBEFORE:")
print(test_1)
print(test_2)
print("EQ: {}".format(test_1 == test_2))

dict_sorter(test_1)
dict_sorter(test_2)

print("\n\nAFTER:")
print(test_1)
print(test_2)
print("EQ: {}".format(test_1 == test_2))
```

**Output with Python2:**

```
>>> python2 test.py

BEFORE:
{'aaa': 111, 'bbb': 222, 'ccc': [{'o': [1, 't']}, 'a', 'b', 1, [1, 2, [4, 3, [6, 5]]]]}
{'aaa': 111, 'bbb': 222, 'ccc': [[2, 1, [3, 4, [5, 6]]], 1, 'a', 'b', {'o': ['t', 1]}]}
EQ: False

AFTER:
{'aaa': 111, 'bbb': 222, 'ccc': [1, {'o': [1, 't']}, [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]], 'a', 'b']}
{'aaa': 111, 'bbb': 222, 'ccc': [1, {'o': [1, 't']}, [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]], 'a', 'b']}
EQ: True
```

**Output with Python3:**

```
>>> python3 test.py

BEFORE:
{'aaa': 111, 'bbb': 222, 'ccc': [{'o': [1, 't']}, 'a', 'b', 1, [1, 2, [4, 3, [6, 5]]]]}
{'bbb': 222, 'aaa': 111, 'ccc': [[2, 1, [3, 4, [5, 6]]], 1, 'a', 'b', {'o': ['t', 1]}]}
EQ: False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    dict_sorter(test_1)
  File "test.py", line 17, in dict_sorter
    v.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'dict'
```

Comment: this will  [help1  how to sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) and [help2 sort different type of object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html), i personally think , when you encounter a list having multiple data type you need to set the priority order for data types, and insteal if sorting the parent list, just sort the inside object dataype seperatly and arrange them in order, second (not fully sure) if possible try to create a sort class same as used in python2.7 and with the help of that solve this issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already read those documentations but they don't solve my problem. Perhaps I can write a sorting class but it would be so complex and it takes big effort (separate the types and sorting them and build again the structure etc...). I hope there is a more simple and effective solution for this sorting.

Comment: i think this is all because of implementation difference because of python2.7 and python3, try numpy, see if it can help, as i am not much familiar with it so cant say much

Comment: @sahasrara62, Sure, I have mentioned in my question that I am aware of the the Python2/Python3 differences.

Answer (score -2):

In python2 comparision between any data to any other data is possible. But, in python3 it is not possible.

[Reference]

https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I mentioned I have already read the Python documentations and I am aware of the differences between Python2/3. I feel this difference a big limitation in Python3. I am interested in a solution or "hack" for this issue.